# MPI in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, mpi, jupyter

I write a Jupyter notebook with code that is meant to be run with `mpirun`. What is the simplest way to do so ?

My current idea is to put at the end of the notebook a bash command exporting the python code to a file, and then another bash cell running the `mpirun` command, like this:

```
%%bash
jupyter nbconvert --to-script notebook.ipynb --output code
```

And then

```
%%bash
mpirun code.py
```

But these bash commands are exported in `code.py` as well, which causes it to crash. Is there a way to ignore these cells ?

More generally, is there a simpler way to run a notebook with mpirun ? Thanks for any idea or help.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/parallel/parallel_mpi.html ?

Comment: No, I'll try, thanks. Unrelated, but I thought IPython was the old version of Jupyter, why do we still need this ? I don't have the command `ipcluster`, I'll install it

Comment: IPython is still the default kernel for jupyter - so it does still apply.